# Group, take duration and set condition within R (dplyr, r)

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a dataset, df:   (the dataset contains over 4000 rows)

```
  DATEB

  9/9/2019 7:51:58 PM
  9/9/2019 7:51:59 PM
  9/9/2019 7:51:59 PM
  9/9/2019 7:52:00 PM
  9/9/2019 7:52:01 PM
  9/9/2019 7:52:01 PM
  9/9/2019 7:52:02 PM
  9/9/2019 7:52:03 PM
  9/9/2019 7:54:00 PM
  9/9/2019 7:54:02 PM
  9/10/2019 8:00:00PM
```

I am wanting to place these in separate groups, and take the duration, if the time between date-time exceeds 120 seconds.

Desired output:

```
Group   Duration

 a       5 sec
 b       2 sec
 c       0 sec




 dput:


  structure(list(DATEB = structure(c(2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
  7L, 8L, 9L, 1L), .Label = c("      9/10/2019 8:00:00 PM", "      9/9/2019 7:51:58 PM", 
  "      9/9/2019 7:51:59 PM", "      9/9/2019 7:52:00 PM", "      9/9/2019 7:52:01 PM", 
  "      9/9/2019 7:52:02 PM", "      9/9/2019 7:52:03 PM", "      9/9/2019 7:54:00 PM", 
  "      9/9/2019 7:54:02 PM"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
  -11L))
```

I have tried the code below, which works well, except I am wanting the 7:51:59 and 7:52:00 to be in the same group. The only time the duration should break and create a new group, is when the time in between datetimes exceed 120 secs.

```
   df %>%
   mutate(DATEB = lubridate::mdy_hms(DATEB), 
   temp = floor_date(DATEB, "120 secs")) %>%
   group_by(temp) %>%
   summarise(duration = difftime(max(DATEB), min(DATEB), units = "secs"))
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for a *gap* or *pause* longer than a given threshold between *subsequent* date-times? Your words "*the time in between datetimes exceed 120 secs*" do suggest this.

Comment: I mean if the time between previous rows is longer than a given time period, I wish to create a new group along with its duration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `cut` here :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(DATEB = lubridate::mdy_hms(DATEB), 
        temp = cut(DATEB, breaks = "2 mins")) %>%
  group_by(temp) %>%
  summarise(duration = difftime(max(DATEB), min(DATEB), units = "secs"))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  temp                duration
#  <fct>               <drtn>  
#1 2019-09-09 19:51:00 5 secs  
#2 2019-09-09 19:53:00 2 secs  
#3 2019-09-10 19:59:00 0 secs
```

Comment: Hi @Ronak, the code seems to be cutting the time off up until the 'break' time. For my large dataset, I am wanting the break to only apply between datetime values. If this occurs: 5:59:59  6:00:00  6:03:00 6:03:01 so the break occurs between 6:00:00 and 6:03:03. The above code seems to cut the time off once the group reaches the breaktime.

Comment: How can I adjust the code to check previous row in datetime, if time is greater than a certain value (10sec ) place in a group and take its duration

Answer (score 1):

The OP has asked for:

> The only time the duration should break and create a new group, is
>   when the time in between datetimes exceed 120 secs.

The words "*the time in between datetimes*" suggest the OP is looking for a *gap* or *pause*. (Well, this is what I would look for if I've been given a vector of ordered date-times and been tasked to group the data.)

Unfortunately, the expected result and accepted answer do not correspond to this interpretation.

However, here is what I would do:

```
gap_threshold <- 10
df %>%
  mutate(DATEB = lubridate::mdy_hms(DATEB), 
         gap = c(0, diff(DATEB))) %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(gap > gap_threshold)) %>% 
  summarise(begin = min(DATEB), end = max(DATEB), duration = difftime(end, begin, units = "secs"))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 4
>     grp begin               end                 duration
>   <int> <dttm>              <dttm>              <drtn>  
> 1     0 2019-09-09 19:51:58 2019-09-09 19:52:03 5 secs  
> 2     1 2019-09-09 19:54:00 2019-09-09 19:54:02 2 secs  
> 3     2 2019-09-10 20:00:00 2019-09-10 20:00:00 0 secs
> ```